# How to send large xml files from wcf service

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

The solution below works for sending small xml files from WCF service to client.

```
public interface IBatchDataExport
{
[OperationContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "export/{filename}")]
XmlDocument GetExportData(string filename);
}

...

public XmlDocument GetExportData(string filename)
{
System.Net.HttpStatusCode status = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(filename);
return xml;
}
```

But for large files I get OutOfMemoryException exception in xml.Load(filename).

What is the best way to send large xml files from wcf service?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend sending `XML` file as [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx). Stream helps in reading data when it is large as in your case and thus impractical to load all data at once.

See [File Transfer with WCF](http://stefanoricciardi.com/2009/08/28/file-transfer-with-wcp/) for more details

Answer (score 3):

You can send the **xml in chunks** and process the xml in **chunks** as well. Because **XmlDocument** load the entire xml in memory, so it could give out of memory.